# Why is $\{x/2\}$ always either $\{x\}/2$ or $\{x\}/2 + 1/2$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

I was working on a problem involving floor functions and fractional parts. The question is to prove that $\lfloor x \rfloor - 2 \cdot \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$ is either $0$ or $1$. In one of the solutions provided, the statement was made that 'the fractional part of $\frac{x}{2}$ is always either ${\frac{\{x\}}{2}}$ or ${\frac{\{x\}}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}$.' While I have verified this statement through examples, I am seeking a clear explanation, supported by examples, as to why ${\frac{\{x\}}{2}}$ is consistently 'always' either ${\frac{\{x\}}{2}}$ or ${\frac{\{x\}}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hint: write $x=\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$ and distinguish cases $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is odd and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is even.

Comment: the question is for x in R not only in Z ..

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is always in $\mathbb Z$, no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: okk but what do you think of the statement that confused me that {x/2} is "always" either {x}/2 or {x}/2 + 1/2 ? I really want someone to explain this part to me It got me stuck for 2 weeks on it lol I don't know if I'm stupid or it's something that I don't know at all

Comment: The hint was to write x=[x]+{x} and to look at the two cases when [x] is odd and even. Did not help it? What do you think [x/2] is equal to in the two cases? How this can be used to obtain {x/2}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the original problem $\lfloor x\rfloor-2\lfloor x/2\rfloor\in\{0, 1\}$ more elementary than what you are asking. In fact, only by using inequalities:

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\le x< \lfloor x\rfloor+1$$
$$\lfloor x/2\rfloor\le x/2< \lfloor x/2\rfloor+1$$

you conclude

$$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$
$$x/2-1<\lfloor x/2\rfloor\le x/2$$

The second inequality (when multiplied by $-2$ and reversed) gives you this:

$$-x\le-2\lfloor x/2\rfloor<-x+2$$

Add to the first:

$$-1<\lfloor x\rfloor-2\lfloor x/2\rfloor<2$$

so as $\lfloor x\rfloor-2\lfloor x/2\rfloor$ is an *integer* strictly between $-1$ and $2$, it can only be $0$ or $1$.

---

Now, if you want to answer your question directly, I suggest you distinguish the cases $\lfloor x\rfloor$ odd and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ even.

If $\lfloor x\rfloor=2n$ is even, this means $x=2n+\{x\}$. Then,

$$\frac{x}{2}=\underbrace{n}_\text{integer}+\underbrace{\frac{\{x\}}{2}}_{\text{between }0\text{ and }1}$$

and, because $0\le\{x\}<1$ you have $0\le \frac{\{x\}}{2}<\frac{1}{2}<1$ and so $\frac{\{x\}}{2}$ must be the fractional part of $\frac{x}{2}$. (Why? Because we have just written $\frac{x}{2}$ as a sum of an integer $n$ and something in the interval $[0,1)$.) So in that case $\left\{\frac{x}{2}\right\}=\frac{\{x\}}{2}$.

If $\lfloor x\rfloor=2n+1$ is odd, this means $x=2n+1+\{x\}$. Then:

$$\frac{x}{2}=\underbrace{n}_\text{integer}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\{x\}}{2}}_{\text{between }0\text{ and }1}$$

and, because $0\le\frac{\{x\}}{2}<\frac{1}{2}$ we also have that $0\le\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{\{x\}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}<1$, so, similar to the first case, $\frac{\{x\}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ must be the fractional part of $\frac{x}{2}$. So in that case $\left\{\frac{x}{2}\right\}=\frac{\{x\}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Good answer, I like it (+1).

Comment: Thank you so so much, you are an angel

Comment: I find this quite funny. OP is calling StinkingBishop an angel in front of @Angelo, whose username means angel in Italian.